# Angular 6 animation forwards (animation-fill-mode in Angular)

Tags: javascript, css, angular, animation, angular6

I have a property which is animated with CSS and works fine:

```
animation: collapse1 0.3s forwards;
```

But now I need to switch to angular animations. And everything works fine, except one thing: after animation finished, it returns to the starting point.

Now it works like this:

```
animation: collapse1 0.3s;
```

but it should work like this:

```
animation: collapse1 0.3s forwards;
```

In other words, is it possible to provide animation-fill-mode in Angular? I'm using Angular 6.

Here is the demo: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uw3o6u

Demo has 2 buttons.

It works when user moves mouse to the button (:hover css).
But I need this behavior when user clicks the button (case 2).

The final position after click should be this:

[image]

But it returns to the beginning:

[image]

---

I solved it by CSS classes:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdfgxw

But it still not an Angular animation.

Does anybody know how to solve it using Angular animation? Is it possible?

Comment: what do your states look like, need more info, preferably a stackblitz - thx

Comment: @danday74, I updated with demo

Comment: As per your demo it is working fine on the click (button 2)

Comment: Not really. It should stay at the final position, lines should be crossed, but they return to the beginning.

Comment: I solved it by CSS classes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kdfgxw

But it still not an Angular animation.

Does anybody know how to solve it using Angular animation? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. And use to finally solve it by CSS classes like you.

But I found a solution (it was quite simple and obvious arf)..
You must include your final style in a state() function in your case

See:

```
trigger(openCloseAnimation, [
  state('closed', style({ top: '9px', transform: 'rotate(-45deg)', offset: 1 })),
  transition('open => close',animate(300)),
  transition('close => open', animate(300))
])
```

By the way, you cannot use query Inside a state function, so for inner classes you will have to switch for innerTrigger and use animateChild() in the parent trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after spending a few hours understanding better Angular Animations, I came across this link [Transition and Triggers](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers)

For angular animations, when you want the transition to stay in the end, you need to set the `state` that the component should be.

```
animations: [
    trigger('toggleControls', [
      state('show', style({
        opacity: 1, offset: 1, height: '64px', overflow: 'visible'
      })),
      state('hide', style({
        opacity: 0, offset: 1, height: '0', overflow: 'hidden', 
      })),
      transition('show => hide', [
        animate('1s', keyframes([
          style({ opacity: 1, offset: 0, height: '64px', overflow: 'hidden'}), // 0%
          style({ opacity: 0, offset: 0.5, height: '0', overflow: 'hidden'}), // 50%
          style({ opacity: 0, offset: 1, height: '0', overflow: 'hidden'}), // 100%
        ]))
      ]),
      transition('hide => show', [
        animate('1s', keyframes([
          style({ opacity: 0, offset: 0, height: '0', overflow: 'hidden' }), // 0%
          style({ opacity: 0, offset: 0.5, height: '0', overflow: 'hidden' }), // 50%
          style({ opacity: 1, offset: 0.9, height: '64px', overflow: 'hidden' }), // 90%
          style({ opacity: 1, offset: 1, height: '64px', overflow: 'visible' }), // 100%
        ]))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

When you set your state, the CSS will stay on that state in the end, just like the forwards for the animation fill mode.